# Call another controller action using renderPartial

Tags: php, yii, renderpartial

i have problem in calling action from different controller using renderPartial.

I have one controller 'SiteController'. In which i call action from another controller 'AbcController'.

```
$this->renderPartial('Abc/_jobList',array('value'=>$value));
```

But i get following error

SiteController cannot find the requested view "Abc/_jobList".

Even i use

```
$this->renderPartial('//Abc/_jobList',array('value'=>$value));
```

and i get same error.

How can i solve it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to access different controller's view.

For that you can access that by

```
$this->renderPartial('application.views.abc._jobList',array('value'=>$value));
```

But if you want to call another controller action then You have to redirect to that action from your current action using

```
$this->redirect("controllername/functionname")
```